# Detecting two GPS coordinates bounding boxs overlap

Tags: java, .net, gps, numbers

I have two GPS locations. For each I am creating a bounding box in a different range.
Each bounding box has min/max latitude and min/max longitude.

Need to implement a method to detect if those two boxes overlap (don't mind the overlap range.. only true/false). Also, this method will be integrated in a long loop so I am looking for the most efficient way to do it.

note: when saying overlap I mean - "there is at least one single point on the map that is contained in both bounding boxes".

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's enough to check if one of the corners of one rectangle is within the other rectangle. This is true of these two hold:

- rect1.minX *or* rect1.maxX is between rect2.minX and rect2.maxX
  **and**
- rect1.minY *or* rect1.maxY is between rect2.minY and rect2.maxY

This check should take no time at all to do, so efficiency isn't a problem. Also, the order of the arguments is irrelevant.

Comment: But be careful of bounding boxes that cross the date-line, or the poles!

Answer (score 4):

I'm facing the same issue and the previous solution is not sufficient.

This image show cases that are covered and not covered

[image]

I've found this web page that give the correct method to respond to the problem: https://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2009/10/03/determining-if-two-bounding-boxes-overlap/
Here is the implementation of this solution:

> function DoBoundingBoxesIntersect(bb1, bb2) {
>
> ```
>             //First bounding box, top left corner, bottom right corner
>             var ATLx = bb1.TopLeftLatLong.Longitude;
>             var ATLy = bb1.TopLeftLatLong.Latitude;
>             var ABRx = bb1.BottomRightLatLong.Longitude;
>             var ABRy = bb1.BottomRightLatLong.Latitude;
>
>             //Second bounding box, top left corner, bottom right corner
>             var BTLx = bb2.TopLeftLatLong.Longitude;
>             var BTLy = bb2.TopLeftLatLong.Latitude;
>             var BBRx = bb2.BottomRightLatLong.Longitude;
>             var BBRy = bb2.BottomRightLatLong.Latitude;
>
>             var rabx = Math.abs(ATLx + ABRx – BTLx – BBRx);
>             var raby = Math.abs(ATLy + ABRy – BTLy – BBRy);
>
>             //rAx + rBx
>             var raxPrbx = ABRx – ATLx + BBRx – BTLx;
>
>             //rAy + rBy
>             var rayPrby = ATLy – ABRy + BTLy – BBRy;
>
>             if(rabx <= raxPrbx && raby <= rayPrby)
>             {
>                             return true;
>             }
>             return false;
> ```
>
> }

We can adapt the solution like that :

- step 1 : check if the 2 boundingbox overlap on longitude

  - the left longitude of a bondingbox1 is between longMin and longMax of the boundingbox2 OR the right longitude of a bondingbox1 is between longMin and longMax of the boundingbox2
- step 2 : check if the 2 boundingbox overlap on latitude

  - the top latitude of a bondingbox1 is between latMin and latMax of the boundingbox2 OR the bottom longitude of a bondingbox1 is between latMin and latMax of the boundingbox2
- if step1 and step 2 are right, then the 2 boundingbox overlap

You can see the corresponding sketch here :

[image]

Comment: could you add some content from the site you are referring (with keeping the link as a reference)? This post still doesn't provide a clear answer. So you have a good chance it will be deleted again.

Comment: Your previous comment was deleted because it was giving a link-only answer. Links may change and will not be relevant to your answer. I will help you get the image on your answer, but please add explanation and not only a "me too" answer.

Comment: Please cite text from the link you've provided to avoid getting your answer closed. And no, it's not copyright infringement. Do it like this: `"xxxxxx" - as said from this site http://example.com`

Comment: it's still not an answer - as already mentioned by others you _must include_ the solution (vs. just linking to it)